# Is there any way to set password expiration in embeded LDAP on weblogic

Tags: passwords, weblogic

I'm looking for a way to config password expiration date in embeded LDAP.
I googled it, but it's said that there no way for embeded LDAP. This feature just for external LDAP.

Looking forward to your helps. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe the answer is... no, you will have to write your own custom authenticator (like your google results mentioned).

Comment: are there any happier answers for me ;)